# Reviewing test answers with students using a Course Management System

Tags: coursework, exams

When I give an online test using a Course Management System (aka [Learning Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system), LMS), I like to use the "review answers" capability to go over the test with the class and highlight questions that many of them got incorrect. This can reveal common misunderstandings, poorly worded questions, things I didn't teach adequately, etc.

But given that the recommendation is to scramble the order of the questions and even the answers, how on earth can that work? This is why I DON'T scramble questions and answers.

Does anyone have a way of dealing with this? I have spent hours searching the web and found no reference to this issue. But anyone using a LMS must have encountered it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the following:

1. Students are taking an online test, with questions entered into the LMS
2. The LMS produces some sort of visual output
3. You meet with students face-to-face

I've used our in-house LMS, Moodle and Coursera. In all cases the software offers the students randomized versions of the questions, but produces a view for the instructor that shows student responses that are aggregated (sample given at end of post).
If my assumptions are true, you can pick perhaps the three most often missed questions from the test, make a screenshot, and present this to the class.
Or better yet, offer an often-missed question on a slide and have students work in groups to provide a higher-quality group answer.

We might be able to help you more if you correct my assumptions and provide which LMS you are using.

Sample screen shot:
[image: basic quiz answers]

Comment: I guess that is really the best solution. It just feels more natural to me to have them looking at it and me looking and then I can scroll down and say, Question 1... Question 2... But I guess that doesn't coincide with scrambling the questions. But focusing on 3 or so that caused trouble is more time-effective.

Comment: @user14016, that the questions/answers get scrambled shouldn't be a problem when presenting them to the class for discussion.

Answer (score 3):

[Terascore](http://www.terascore.com) has a built-in way to do this. After the students filled out the test the report shows you question by question how well the whole group did on the question, even showing you which questions are by-design defective - eg. everyone got it wrong, even the top performers.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the founders of Terascore.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation in the answer